# What is the charge of a neutrino

Tags: neutrinos

We know now that neutrino have a very small mass. But it is stated that neutrino have no charge.How is that possible since mass is charge?

Comment: This is unclear. Where did you hear that mass is charge?

Answer (score 1):

Mass is not charge. Charge must be conserved in an interaction. For example, a neutron can decay, giving an electron, a proton, and an electron anti-neutrino. The original neutron has a charge of $0$, and the electron and proton have charges of $-1$ and $+1$ respectively. Therefore, for charge to be conserved, the neutrino must have a charge of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Mass is very similar to electric charge is the sense of the classical physics of gravitational interactions.

However, in terms of particle physics, it is a different sort of property of objects. It is similar to a charge in that it does correlate to the coupling of a boson, namely the Higgs, with the object, but it is not a conserved quantity like color or electric charge. The neutrino has no color or electric charge, so it does not couple to gluons or photons.